# templates and use class object function to compute

Tags: c++, templates, object, vector

i have two vectors of objects bus and car. i need to create a templates to minus the distance travelled by using template. the distance minus will only be done within the same objects like bus1.dis - bus2.dis.

the thing is i am not allow to use overload operator- to code this template, and i need to use getDistance(return dist) method from bus and car classes to do the computation. i have no idea how!!!

anyone knows how to use a class method to use on a template?
my template and class objects is on different header. my template need to take in any object and minus the distance within the same object.

maybe something like T getDistance() - T getDistance() ....

templates.h

```
template <class T>
double dist_difference(T x,T y) {
double distance = x.getDist() - y.getDist();
return distance;
}
```

bus.h

```
class bus{

private:
int dist;

public:
int getDist();
void setDist(int);
};
```

car.h

```
class car {

private:
int dist;

public:
int getDist();
void setDist(int);
};
```

Comment: It's generally better to post code than to talk about what it does. Your question would be much easier to understand if we saw the definitions of the classes.

Comment: Appart from the syntax error (missing `}`), from the info you gave us your function `template<class T> double dist_difference(T x, T y);` seems to be ok.

Comment: no the template is just what i wanted it to be.. the thing is i cant even put my method in the template, like x.getDist is not do-able. thats why i want to know how to use class method in template.i  think i am missing something, like linking the class to the template to allow me to use its function

Comment: ...and as well noted by @hmjd, if you plan to compare `car`s WITH `bus`es, the types for `x` and `y` have to be different.

Comment: no i only need to compare within the same object, car with car and bus with bus distances.

Comment: i know how to use template properly with operator- , but not with using their class function in the template that is in different header. thats what i am confused with. first time doing it.

Comment: Calling a class' function should work the same way as using the `operator -` inside a template function. The compiler would complain only if type `T` does not define `double getDist()`. What is the error you get when compiling your code?

Comment: type T does not know anything about getDist.. cant use x.getDist. the template above is just something i want. i cant even complete the coding for my template,so cant tell you errors. because x does not allow me to use any function. i am missing some code for linking the templates and the classes i think....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

car.h

```
struct Car {
  int dist;
};
```

dist.h

```
template<class T>
int distDiff(T x, T y) {
  return x.dist - y.dist;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "car.h"
#include "dist.h"

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Car a;
  a.dist = 10;

  Car b;
  b.dist = 5;

  int dist = distDiff(a, b);
  std::cout << dist << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
5
```

The type `T` can be any type that defines the attribute `dist`. The compiler ensures it when you use the function, since for each different type `T`, it derives a specialized version of it.

Comment: oh thanks!! so you can just use the function and run it...because it doesnt seems logical when the program never show anything when i do 'x.' i though it will surely be a error...stupid me..

Comment: Auto-complete does not work because you don't know which form the type `T` will take until compilation. You can think of `T` as a common interface shared between all the types of the arguments you provide to the template function throughout your project.